# how to make view with a separate submenu that belongs to panel?

Tags: views

My name is Leith from Korea

I have a question

what I try to make is a dynamic pages with panel and view like this

main menu : A | B | C ( C is the menu having sub menu )

sub menu area : AA | BB | CC | DD | EE

content area : when clicking on each content, content area shows of each content.

I found the solution :

1. create one view page, and then clone 5 different views with filter conditions for each sub menu by using texonomy.
   set the path to each views like /C/AA, /C/BB, /C/CC, /C/DD, /C/EE
   and then as for the views for sub menu, menu setting be menu tab.

until now everything is good. but "I want to put this view in panel then, I can control the layout of the dynamic views". 
but as far as I know view page cannot be put into panel. the only thing can be put into panel is view block rather than view page.
and also mini-panel is like block, so there is no way to create sub menu. it only show just one view with one filter condition

Is there any way to put the view page into panel page?

or is there better way you can suggest me?

I want to make a board exactly the same as this board

it has sub menu 
when click the sub menu, it filters to the related posts on the table
and I think it belongs to panel.

Comment: As far as i know you can put a view page in a panel as well. Are you using Views content panes module?